# SharePoint 2010 Products Configuration Wizard failed to register SharePoint services - LocStringId parameter

Tags: sharepoint

I have a two tier SharePoint 2010 (one server is application and the other is the SQL Server). I was able to install SharePoint with SP1 but when I am in the Products Configuration Wizard it fails on step 6 (or is it step 5?) of the process, failed to register SharePoint services. Please help, I have been working a long time on this and have found no help anywhere and everything I have checked has not led me to a solution. I have tried restarting the servers, IIS, uninstalling SharePoint and reinstalling everything but still the same problem. Any advice would be much appreciated, thanks.

An exception of type System.InvalidOperationException was thrown.

Additional exception information: The specified value for the LocStringId parameter is outside the bounds of this enum.

Microsoft.Office.Server.ApplicationRegistry.SharedService.ApplicationRegistryServiceInstance, Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,

PublicKeyToken=71E9BCE111E9429C
03/23/2012 15:40:55  1  INF                                  Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
03/23/2012 15:40:55  10  INF                                Leaving function ServicesTask.InvokeServiceConstructor
03/23/2012 15:40:55  1  INF                                Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
03/23/2012 15:40:55  1  INF                                Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
03/23/2012 15:40:55  1  INF                                Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  ERR                                Task services has failed with an unknown exception 
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  ERR                                Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: The specified value for the LocStringId parameter is outside

the bounds of this enum.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.StringResourceManager.ConvertLocStringIdToStringFast(LocStringId lsid)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.StringResourceManager.GetString(LocStringId lsid)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.ApplicationRegistry.SharedService.ApplicationRegistryServiceInstance.get_TypeName()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ServicesTask.InstallServiceInstanceInConfigDB(Boolean provisionTheServiceInstanceToo, String

serviceInstanceRegistryKeyName, Object sharepointServiceObject)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ServicesTask.InstallServiceInstances(Boolean provisionTheServiceInstancesToo, String serviceRegistryKeyName, Object

sharepointServiceObject)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ServicesTask.InstallServices(Boolean provisionTheServicesToo)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ServicesTask.Run()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                Entering function Common.BuildExceptionMessage
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                  Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                    Resource id to be retrieved is ExceptionInfo for language English (United States)
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                    Resource retrieved id ExceptionInfo is An exception of type {0} was thrown.  Additional exception

information: {1}
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                  Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionMessage
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                Entering function Common.BuildExceptionInformation
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                  Entering function Common.BuildExceptionMessage
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                    Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                      Resource id to be retrieved is ExceptionInfo for language English (United States)
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                      Resource retrieved id ExceptionInfo is An exception of type {0} was thrown.  Additional exception

information: {1}
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                    Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                  Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionMessage
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionInformation
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  ERR                                An exception of type System.InvalidOperationException was thrown.  Additional exception information: The

specified value for the LocStringId parameter is outside the bounds of this enum.
System.InvalidOperationException: The specified value for the LocStringId parameter is outside the bounds of this enum.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.StringResourceManager.ConvertLocStringIdToStringFast(LocStringId lsid)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.StringResourceManager.GetString(LocStringId lsid)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.ApplicationRegistry.SharedService.ApplicationRegistryServiceInstance.get_TypeName()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ServicesTask.InstallServiceInstanceInConfigDB(Boolean provisionTheServiceInstanceToo, String

serviceInstanceRegistryKeyName, Object sharepointServiceObject)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ServicesTask.InstallServiceInstances(Boolean provisionTheServiceInstancesToo, String serviceRegistryKeyName, Object

sharepointServiceObject)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ServicesTask.InstallServices(Boolean provisionTheServicesToo)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ServicesTask.Run()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                Entering function Common.BuildExceptionInformation
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                  Entering function Common.BuildExceptionMessage
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                    Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                      Resource id to be retrieved is ExceptionInfo for language English (United States)
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                      Resource retrieved id ExceptionInfo is An exception of type {0} was thrown.  Additional exception

information: {1}
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                    Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                  Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionMessage
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                Leaving function Common.BuildExceptionInformation
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                Entering function get CommandCollection.this[string key]
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                  Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                    Found value in collection for key global
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                  Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                  Found command global in collection
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                Leaving function get CommandCollection.this[string key]
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                Entering function get CommandCollection.this[string key]
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                  Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                    Found value in collection for key initialize
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                  Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                  Found command initialize in collection
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                Leaving function get CommandCollection.this[string key]
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                Entering function Command.this[string key]
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                  Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                    Found value in collection for key SINGLESERVER
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                  Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                  Found parameter SINGLESERVER in collection
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                Leaving function Command.this[string key]
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                Entering function Command.this[string key]
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                  Entering function CommandCollectionBase.Get
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                    Found value in collection for key upgradesessionid
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                  Leaving function CommandCollectionBase.Get
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                  Found parameter upgradesessionid in collection
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                Leaving function Command.this[string key]
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                Entering function TaskBase.OnTaskStop
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                  Creating the OnTaskStop event for task services
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  ERR                                  Task services has failed
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                  friendlyMessage for task services is An exception of type System.InvalidOperationException was thrown.

Additional exception information: The specified value for the LocStringId parameter is outside the bounds of this enum.
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                  debugMessage for task services is An exception of type System.InvalidOperationException was thrown.

Additional exception information: The specified value for the LocStringId parameter is outside the bounds of this enum.
System.InvalidOperationException: The specified value for the LocStringId parameter is outside the bounds of this enum.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.StringResourceManager.ConvertLocStringIdToStringFast(LocStringId lsid)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.StringResourceManager.GetString(LocStringId lsid)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.ApplicationRegistry.SharedService.ApplicationRegistryServiceInstance.get_TypeName()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ServicesTask.InstallServiceInstanceInConfigDB(Boolean provisionTheServiceInstanceToo, String

serviceInstanceRegistryKeyName, Object sharepointServiceObject)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ServicesTask.InstallServiceInstances(Boolean provisionTheServiceInstancesToo, String serviceRegistryKeyName, Object

sharepointServiceObject)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ServicesTask.InstallServices(Boolean provisionTheServicesToo)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ServicesTask.Run()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                  Entering function TaskBase.FireTaskStateChanged
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                    Firing the OnTaskStateChanged event for task services
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                    Entering function TaskDriver.TaskStateEventHandler
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                      Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                        Resource id to be retrieved is ServicesTaskDisplayName for language English (United States)
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                        Resource retrieved id ServicesTaskDisplayName is service registration
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                      Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                      Received an TaskStateEventHandler event.  task:services TaskBase.State:stopped
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                      Entering function TasksQueue.IncrementTaskFailed
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                        Incremented the number of tasks failed to 1
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                      Leaving function TasksQueue.IncrementTaskFailed
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                      Task services has stopped and failed.  Total failed is now 1
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                    Leaving function TaskDriver.TaskStateEventHandler
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                    Entering function PsconfigBaseForm.TaskStateEventHandler
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                      Invoking the UI thread with the task state chagne event
03/23/2012 15:40:56  1  INF                                      Entering function ConfigurationProgressForm.InvokeTaskStateEventHandler
03/23/2012 15:40:56  1  INF                                        Received an TaskStateEventHandler event.  task:services TaskBase.State:stopped

TaskBase.TaskResultservices
03/23/2012 15:40:56  1  INF                                        Acquiring the reader lock to retrieve the state
03/23/2012 15:40:56  1  INF                                        Releasing the reader lock to retrieve the state
03/23/2012 15:40:56  1  INF                                        Acquiring the reader lock to retrieve the state
03/23/2012 15:40:56  1  INF                                        Releasing the reader lock to retrieve the state
03/23/2012 15:40:56  1  INF                                        Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
03/23/2012 15:40:56  1  INF                                        Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
03/23/2012 15:40:56  1  INF                                        Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
03/23/2012 15:40:56  1  INF                                        Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
03/23/2012 15:40:56  1  INF                                        Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
03/23/2012 15:40:56  1  ERR                                        Task services has stopped and failed.  Total failed is now 1
03/23/2012 15:40:56  1  INF                                        Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
03/23/2012 15:40:56  1  INF                                          Resource id to be retrieved is ServicesTaskFailConfigDisplayLabel for language English (United

States)
03/23/2012 15:40:56  1  INF                                          Resource retrieved id ServicesTaskFailConfigDisplayLabel is Failed to register SharePoint

services.
03/23/2012 15:40:56  1  INF                                        Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
03/23/2012 15:40:56  1  INF                                        Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
03/23/2012 15:40:56  1  INF                                        Updating the task label below the progress bar Failed to register SharePoint services.
03/23/2012 15:40:56  1  INF                                        Entering function FormParameterCollection.Add
03/23/2012 15:40:56  1  INF                                        Leaving function FormParameterCollection.Add
03/23/2012 15:40:56  1  INF                                        Last message from task services is An exception of type System.InvalidOperationException was thrown.

Additional exception information: The specified value for the LocStringId parameter is outside the bounds of this enum.
03/23/2012 15:40:56  1  INF                                        Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
03/23/2012 15:40:56  1  INF                                        Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
03/23/2012 15:40:56  1  INF                                        Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
03/23/2012 15:40:56  1  INF                                        Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
03/23/2012 15:40:56  1  INF                                        Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
03/23/2012 15:40:56  1  INF                                        Updating the task additional notification information below the progress bar An exception of type

System.InvalidOperationException was thrown.  Additional exception information: The specified value for the LocStringId parameter is outside the bounds of this enum.
03/23/2012 15:40:56  1  INF                                      Leaving function ConfigurationProgressForm.InvokeTaskStateEventHandler
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                      Sleeping an extra 1 ms so things don't go too fast for the user for this task
03/23/2012 15:40:56  1  INF                                      Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
03/23/2012 15:40:56  1  INF                                      Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
03/23/2012 15:40:56  1  INF                                      Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
03/23/2012 15:40:56  1  INF                                      Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
03/23/2012 15:40:56  1  INF                                      Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
03/23/2012 15:40:56  1  INF                                      Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
03/23/2012 15:40:56  1  INF                                      Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
03/23/2012 15:40:56  1  INF                                      Not running in high contrast, so we will paint the background with our trademarked image
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                    Leaving function PsconfigBaseForm.TaskStateEventHandler
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                  Leaving function TaskBase.FireTaskStateChanged
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                                Leaving function TaskBase.OnTaskStop
03/23/2012 15:40:56  10  INF                              Leaving function TaskThread.ExecuteTask
03/23/2012 15:40:56  9  INF                              Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
03/23/2012 15:40:56  9  INF                                Resource id to be retrieved is ServicesTaskDisplayName for language English (United States)
03/23/2012 15:40:56  9  INF                                Resource retrieved id ServicesTaskDisplayName is service registration
03/23/2012 15:40:56  9  INF                              Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
03/23/2012 15:40:56  9  ERR                              Task service registration failed, so stopping execution of the engine
03/23/2012 15:40:56  9  INF                              Entering function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
03/23/2012 15:40:56  9  INF                                Resource id to be retrieved is ServicesTaskFailConfigDisplayLabel for language English (United States)
03/23/2012 15:40:56  9  INF                                Resource retrieved id ServicesTaskFailConfigDisplayLabel is Failed to register SharePoint services.
03/23/2012 15:40:56  9  INF                              Leaving function StringResourceManager.GetResourceString
03/23/2012 15:40:56  9  ERR                              Failed to register SharePoint services.
An exception of type System.InvalidOperationException was thrown.  Additional exception information: The specified value for the LocStringId parameter is outside the

bounds of this enum.
System.InvalidOperationException: The specified value for the LocStringId parameter is outside the bounds of this enum.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.StringResourceManager.ConvertLocStringIdToStringFast(LocStringId lsid)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.StringResourceManager.GetString(LocStringId lsid)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.ApplicationRegistry.SharedService.ApplicationRegistryServiceInstance.get_TypeName()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ServicesTask.InstallServiceInstanceInConfigDB(Boolean provisionTheServiceInstanceToo, String

serviceInstanceRegistryKeyName, Object sharepointServiceObject)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ServicesTask.InstallServiceInstances(Boolean provisionTheServiceInstancesToo, String serviceRegistryKeyName, Object

sharepointServiceObject)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ServicesTask.InstallServices(Boolean provisionTheServicesToo)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.ServicesTask.Run()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.TaskThread.ExecuteTask()

---

Answer (score 0):

I was able to complete my installation by using a different installation file for SharePoint. The one that I had issues with already included Service Pack 1, I tried that one without the service pack included and was able to complete the Configuration Wizard, the Windows Updates had already upgraded the installation to SP1.

Answer (score 0):

Using two SP Powershell commands instead of SP Wizard issue worked for me...

To help resolve security issues:

```
psconfig.exe -cmd secureresources
```

To do the upgrade (this is actually recommended over the SP Wizard):

```
PSCONFIG.EXE -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b
```